# Storing XML from a web service in C#

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

Quick simple question really.

I'm sending data to a web service in C# and its giving me XML back.  It is a SOAP 1.1 and/or 1.2 web service.  I'm not sure how to properly recieve this data and then get the information I need out of it.

Here is my code to send it

```
try
{
  _webService.ProcessCard(sVariable1, sVariable2);

}
catch ( Exception d )
{

}
```

And here is what I get back if I manually use the service through a browser

```
<Response>
  <Result>24</Result>
  <RespMSG>Invalid</RespMSG>
  <ExtData>More Data</ExtData>
</Response>
```

Here is the service definition:

```
    public Response ProcessCard(string sVariable1, string sVariable2 ) {
      object[] results = this.Invoke("ProcessCard", new object[] {
        sVariable1,
        sVariable2});
      return ((Response)(results[0]));
    }
```

Comment: What do you intend to do with the resulting data?

Comment: What is the return of ProcessCard?  Is your web service a SOAP web service?  REST?  Something else WCF?  Are there other members of the _webService instance?  Can we see the class definition, at least in terms of methods and properties?

Comment: Added more info to OP and other comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does that "webService.ProcessCard" method return anything? Does it return a string of XML, or a structured data type?

Show us the method definition for `ProcessCard`, please!

So the ProcessCard method returns an object of type `Response` - so you just simply use that:

```
try
{
    Response myResponse = _webService.ProcessCard(sVariable1, sVariable2);

    // do whatever you like and need to do with myResponse
    .......
}
catch ( Exception d )
{

}
```

Once you have that "response" object - you can do anything you want with it - store it, show it on screen, do some calculations.....

The whole point of web services (ASP.NET ASMX or WCF) is that **you** don't have to struggle with angle bracket soup (i.e. lots of low-level XML stuff), but you can focus and concentrate on your real issues and work with neat, useful objects.

Cool, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying.  It a SOAP web service.  It returns an object of type response, that's what I'm not sure how to accept and store.  If it was a string I'd be ok.

I'll add the definition above.

I plan to display the data, so I need to access the "Invalid" and the "More Data", etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something along the lines of

```
Response response = _webService.ProcessCard( sVariable1, sVariable2 );
DoSomethingToResult( response.Result );
```